# Update a list with Ajax/JSON from MYSQL Database

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i have a small problem.

My Database Query give me a json result like this:

```
[
{"id":"8","bf_id":"4","technik_id":"34","art":"8","status":"open","date":"1372880586",
"comment":"Test 1","user":"1","status_change_date":"1386800040",
"status_change_userid":"45"},
]
```

Now i want to show the results in a simple "list":

```
    setInterval(function(){    
$.getJSON('test/data.php', function (data) {
    var output = '<strong>Technische St&ouml;rungen</strong>';
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        output += '<a href="#"><span class="user-status ' + val.id + ' "></span><em>' + val.id + '</em></a>';
    });
    $('#brot').html(output);  // replace all existing content
});
}, 1000);
```

I "know" the mistake. The File is not data.json. When i make a ne file data.json with static variables it works. But i get the Information from my database. What can I do now?

Greetings

Comment: Just to warn, an `.ajax()` query every `1000 milliseconds` is rather, intensive.

Comment: This is only for test usage

Answer (score 0):

Try to append data to your div

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('test/data.php', function(data) {
            .done(function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                    $("#brot").append('<a href="#"><span class="user-status ' + item.id + ' "></span><em>' + item.id + '</em></a>');
                });
            });
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: With this Code happens nothing! Sorry

Answer (score 0):

change the following line val.id to val only it will show all data:

```
output += '<a href="#"><span class="user-status ' + val.id + ' "></span><em>' + val.id + '</em></a>';

output += '<a href="#"><span class="user-status ' + val+ ' "></span><em>' + val + '</em></a>';
```

Comment: The result is [object Object]